# how to multi line regex match each distinct entry of a log file

Tags: regex

For a log file, I'm trying to get a match for each distinct entry even if it spans multiple lines. Each distinct entry will begin with a timestamp even if there are multiple lines pertaining to the entry.

**Here is my log file:**

```
2000-01-01 01:01:01 UTC This is a 2 line sentence.
This is the second line
2000-01-01 01:01:02 UTC some random text on 1 line
2000-01-01 01:01:03 UTC This is a much longer 1 line sentence that manages to wrap itself around because of its length
2022-01-01 01:01:04 UTC This multi line paragraph has a few blank lines in between lines of text
           words words words and some numbers12345

a few more words
more words on another line and the next line might be blank

2000-01-01 01:01:05 UTC some random text on 1 line
2000-01-01 06:01:06 UTC This multi line paragraph has a few blank lines in between lines of text
           words words words and some numbers678910

a few more words
more words on another line and the next line might be blank

2000-01-01 01:01:07 UTC some random text on one line
```

I'm trying to match essentially any line that does **not** begin with a timestamp.

This works well as a base, but it won't grab any entry that spans multiple lines: 
`^([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} UTC [[][0-9]+[]]: [[][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[]] .+\n)`

I've tried adding to it to do a negative lookahead to try and get each distinct entry as a match like so, but it's not right and I get even less matches: `^([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} UTC .+\n)(.+\n)*(?!([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} UTC))`

**Is there a way to construct a regex to grab each distinct entry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example seems to take milliseconds into account, which I don't see in your logs.

You could do with a positive lookahead:

```
^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} UTC) (.*?)(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|\z)
```

It grabs the log text until it encounters another timestamp, or the end of the input (`\z`), and captures the timestamp and log entry separately.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bqwBtZ/1)

Comment: I took out the milliseconds part I had mistakenly left in my example

Answer (score 1):

From your first Regex, I do not understand why you are using `[[][0-9]+[]]: [[][0-9]+[-][0-9]+[]] .+\n` after `UTC` and what `[.][0-9]+` should be good for.

However, this is how you could make it work with Negative Lookahead:

```
^(?![0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} UTC).*
```

So it will ignore lines which start with a timestamp until `UTC`.

[See the result](https://regex101.com/r/TYenRv/1)